# Making Selenium Chromedriver controlled browser save yubikey based authentication sessions like normal browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I'm using ***Python with Selenium*** to extract some data from a webpage through automation. That webpage normally requires one-time yubikey based authentication per day.

However, when `.get()`ing that page using `Chrome Webdriver`, it asks for authentication each time and I need to add `wait()` in my script in order to manually authenticate first before reaching the target page.

I think the webdriver controlled browser doesn't save authentication sessions like a normal browser does.

Is it possible to make the webdriver controlled browser save authentication sessions normally so that I don't have to manually authenticate every time I `get()` it?

Comment: do you need to install an addon/extension to use yubikey?  (Seems like it would need that to read the usb stick...)

Comment: @pcalkins no, I don't need to install any addon/extension for yubikey. It's just plug and use.

Answer (score 0):

This example will use the cookies to log you into stackoverflow.com after you login and save the cookies.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pickle

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Path\\To\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')

time.sleep(60)
#########################

#LOGIN TO STACKOVERFLOW

########################
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("C:/Path/to/cookie/cookies.pkl","wb"))
driver.close()

time.sleep(5)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Path\\To\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
cookies = pickle.load(open("C:/Path/to/cookie/cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

---

---

---

After the cookie is saved you can just use the cookie.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pickle


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Path\\To\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
cookies = pickle.load(open("C:/Path/to/cookie/cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Comment: Thanks @jortega will try this and let you know how it goes.